# Keep Track Of Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, networking, client

Newbie here..

I just want to ask how can I accomplish my homework in school.
I basically have this need.

I want to send an ajax request every 10 seconds but I dont want to initiate another request if my previous request has not returned yet.

I am thinking that the connection to DB might be that bad sometimes  so I would like to wait for my previous request to be finished (success/failed/error) before I fire up another.

I check on javascript and and found the setinterval method.  But how can I line up my ajax request so that the server doesnt get fired up by many ajax request?

I am studying jquery right now and is using JSON.

Comment: SO, is not for doing your homework.

Comment: I don't see why this question should be downvoted, the English is not ideal but it is a legitimate question. I encourage downvoters to show some tolerance to those who are new to programming.

Comment: @Starx: We have a homework tag with over 4000 posts.

Comment: @kbrimington, exactly my point, why are we solving from that 4000 homeworks....

Comment: @Starx: Almost every problem posted to this site could have not been asked and solved by the asker themselves via research and dedication. The purpose here is not to answer mind-binding questions in a unique way, it is to help people on a 1:Many basis with specific problems and gaps in their knowledge. Don't expect unique questions here.

Comment: @silky... if you are so willing and defensive to do his coding for him. i have nothing more to say

Comment: @Starx: Fair question, which has been discussed on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The way I see it, is that this person is telling us he is dooing his homework, and asking us for help on how HE should do it, not asking us to do it for him.

he is also asking for a very specific problem, not a whole solution for his work. it seems fair to help him out

Answer (score 4):

One method would be to set a variable to false when you send out a request. When you get it back set it back to true.  When you go to send out a new ajax request make sure the value is true.  If not add it to a queue of some sort so that it will be called when the request is finished.  However if every request takes longer then ten seconds your queue will get pretty backed up.  So you may not want a queue.  So instead when you go to send out the ajax request if the variable is false you just wait another ten seconds.

Comment: make sure you stop doing requests if you get to many failed ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'll even help more:

```
    var isWatingForResponse = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'wherever'
        ,dataType: 'json'
        ,beforeSend: function() {
            if(isWatingForResponse) {
                return false;
            }
            isWatingForResponse = true;
        }
        ,complete: function() {
            isWatingForResponse = false;
        }
        ,success: function (data) {
            //process data
        }
    });
```

Or follow @qw3n answer. This should work with jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

As I see the OP question:

#### How to set up fault-tolerance on the client-side because of Db-server issues, using jQuery Ajax?

This IMHO, is a really good question.
If I may, I would like to map out the pipe:

`web-client->network->web-server->network->Db-server`

`Db-server->network->web-server->network->web-client`

Your solution to this problem of handling issues with the `db-server` in the client is workable, but really does not address the actual problem. It could really cripple you for future extension of your client.

You should really be handling this issue as close to the problem as possible. In the web-server.